# syn flood size per second

Tags: network, attacks, exploit

Given the size of a TCP packet is 60 bytes, there is a SYN Flood attack on a computer made ​​by a 100 Mb bandwidth, the question is how many syn packets are sent in a second? Is there any formula for calculating?

Answer (score 3):

Attack using 100 Mbps link means you have to create roughly 210k packets to fully utilize your 100 Mbps connection.

100 Mbps = 12500000 Bytes

12500000 / 60 Bytes = 208333.3333333333 Packets

Depending on your machine you will require multiple processes to generate this amount of packets, single process won't generate these many packets in one second.

Comment: You might have dropped a decimal place somewhere.  2.1 million is not the same as 208333.  The second value seems like the correct one to me.  I recently had a SYN-flood directed at me and it was 70Mbps and 140,000 packets per second.

Comment: @Ladadadada - Thanks, ya I didn't see carefully, It should be 210k :)